# Altering Excel TableStyle is being blocked by Sheet Protection?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to programmatically add TableStyles to a workbook. I'm running into a strange issue where I am not able to edit my custom TableStyle while any open worksheet is protected (even Protected with `UserInterfaceOnly = true`).

Take this example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ts As TableStyle

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ts = wb.TableStyles.Add("newts")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    ts.TableStyleElements(xlWholeTable).Interior.Color = 1 'this throws error 1004

End Sub
```

By the way, you can use any of the TableStyleElements indexes.

This will work fine if you skip the `ws.Protect` line. It'll work just fine if you step through and manually unprotect the worksheet before executing the `ts.TableStyleElements(xlWholeTable).Interior.Color = 1` line.

I also tried while the active sheet is not protected (but a protected sheet exists in the Workbook) and it fails. It seems that if ANY sheet on the Workbook is protected, I will get this error.

TableStyles should have nothing to do with Worksheets, right? (and even if they did, Protecting the sheet with UserInterfaceOnly should allow changes from VBA), so why on earth is this happening?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Can repro. Did try to add a new style manually when the sheet was protected, and that's not possible. But that doesn't explain the other scenarios where this is failing.

Comment: @BigBen - yes, and you can add a new TableStyle manually on an unprotected sheet while a protected sheet exists in the same workbook. First time I've ever seen Excel built-in controls allowing you to do more than what vba is allowed to do. Very strange stuff.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.